# Where to configure Azure table storage settings in MVC 4 Web API project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-table-storage

Working on a simple (my first) Azure Web Role based on MVC 4 Web API template and trying to figure out how to organize my Azure Table Storage connection settings.

I can successfully write to my Azure Table Storage in the Controller POST handler, like this:

```
    public void Post([FromUri]string param1, [FromUri]string param2)
    {


        MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();

        <do stuff to set up entity>
        ...

        // Entity is ready to insert

        // ** Question: Where should I set this Table settings?  Don't want to construct it with each POST right?
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("PushEventTable");
        TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(myEntity);

        // Execute the insert operation.
        table.Execute(insertOperation);

    }
```

My question is: What's best practice for managing the Table connection info (or other globals I might use in the controller?)  I.e. where in the scope for the Web Role should  make global config settings and objects like these ONCE so all controllers can access them?

Comment: Instead of doing this in controller, I would recommend using repository pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good pratice, separate your code in layers.

Take a look at DDD (Infrastructure part)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56767/Domain-Driven-Design

and also use Repositories as Gaurav said.